# How do I use AOSP resource overlays to change the default apps in launcher3?

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

I have multiple products with varying hardware resources. I want to modify the launcher3 desktop so that certain apps only appear on the hardware for which they are supported.

In `<aosp_root>/device/<company>/<product>/<product>.mk` I have...

```
DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS := $(IMX_DEVICE_PATH)/overlay
```

I can see during a build that some of my overlays take effect. For example, in `.../<product>/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml` all overlays appear to be taking effect.

I have my overlays for launcher3 in `<product>/overaly/packages/apps/Launcher3/res/xml/default_workspace_4x4.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<favorites xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.android.launcher3">
    <favorite
        launcher:packageName="com.android.gallery3d"
        launcher:className="com.android.gallery3d.app.GalleryActivity"
        launcher:container="-101"
        launcher:screen="0"
        launcher:x="2"
        launcher:y="0" />

    <favorite
        launcher:packageName="com.android.documentsui"
        launcher:className="com.android.documentsui.LauncherActivity"
        launcher:container="-101"
        launcher:screen="1"
        launcher:x="3"
        launcher:y="0" />
</favorites>
```

I don't see the overlay taking effect. Any recommendations for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: So far I've only managed to replace strings and colors, I dont suppose you tried to overlay the device_profiles.xml? Im trying to overlay the numColumns and numRows on the home screen but it seems to fail obtaining the launcher namespace fields in the file and complains that "canBeDefault=true" is not found, despite being a carb copy from launcher3

Comment: I gave up and ended up directly modifying the `default_workspace_4x4.xml` file